# Ubuntu 17.10: re-enable IPv6

Tags: networking, ipv6

After successfully disabling IPv6 using this script :

```
echo  'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1'  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo  'net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1'  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo  'net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1'  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
```

I try to re-enable using this script :

```
sed  -i "/net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6/d" /etc/sysctl.conf
sed  -i "/net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6/d" /etc/sysctl.conf
sed  -i "/net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6/d" /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
```

I have verified that the enable script removes the disable lines from the sysctl.conf file.

In each case, I check the result with this :

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

where '1' means disabled and '0' means not.

The re-enable piece does not work.

In each case, the sysctl -p command reloads the /etc/sysctl.conf file. However it seems that the reload simply pulls into its buffer rather than over-writing it completely so that the disabling properties are not removed.

Is this analysis correct?

If so, I don't see an option to clear the sysctl.conf cache. Is there one? Or is there a strategy for this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entries in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and any files included from it specify what sysctl settings will be applied at boot time, or when you run `sudo sysctl -p`. But the absence of an entry in this file means that such a sysctl (of which there are thousands) *will not be changed* from whatever value it currently holds.

You removed the sysctl entries that disabled IPv6 from this file, but it doesn't appear that you actually changed the sysctl settings themselves. Running `sudo sysctl -p` didn't change them, because they were not in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

In order to change these entries back to their defaults, you can either reboot your system, or use `sysctl` to set them explicitly.  For example:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=0
sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=0
```

Comment: Perfect. Just the thing.  Thanks for the explanation.